# Post template with breadcrumb needs to show page navigated from

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, templates, breadcrumb

I have a custom post type, Reports, that contains many categories (custom taxonomies).
These posts are organised in menus on different pages.
So a menu page named "Best Reports" would have multiple sections, ie:

```
*Best Reports*

From Today
(List of posts tagged with the categories of "best" and "today")

From Yesterday
(List of posts tagged with the categories of "best" and "yesterday")
```

Another menu page would look like

```
*Worst Reports*

From Today
(List of posts tagged with the categories of "worst" and "today")

From Yesterday
(List of posts tagged with the categories of "worst" and "yesterday")
```

If I click on a post from the "worst" menu page, I want the breadcrumbs to show on the post:
Home > Worst Reports > Current Post

However, this doesn't seem to be possible because the post is not a child of the page. I cannot add the custom post type as a child of only one of the menu pages, because it must be a child to many menu pages.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of how to show the page I navigated from in the post? The breadcrumb is present in a template that is applied to all posts in Reports post type.

Comment: This is not how breadcrumbs typically work, and is likely to confuse users. Breadcrumbs are supposed to reflect the structure of your website, and are not useful if your site's structure is not strictly hierarchical. If a user wants to go back where they came from, regardless of the site structure, that's what the browser history navigation is for.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I appreciate your thoughtful response. However I think the client has fair reason to be confused when the menu page they navigated from is not in the breadcrumb when they view the post. I would like to know how it would be possible to do this.

Comment: You would need to ask whoever developed your breadcrumb implementation, since WordPress has no such functionality, and 3rd-party themes and plugins are off topic here. Keep in mind that any solution is going to cause you problems with caching and performance.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thank you for taking the time to give this advice